# Knockout JS css "else" conditons

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to do this in Knockout.

```
    <span class="badge" data-bind="text: rank, css: {'badge-success': firstPlace, 
        'badge-warning': !firstPlace}"></span>
```

Where my javascript model class has this method

```
    self.firstPlace = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.rank() == 1;
    });
```

This fails to produce the 'badge-warning' class. I tried a few invocation variations in the data-bind attribute such as `firstPlace == false` and `(!firstPlace)`. Instead I have to add a second inverse method to my model:

```
    <span class="badge" data-bind="text: rank, css: {'badge-success': firstPlace, 
        'badge-warning': notFirstPlace}"></span>


    // YUCK
    self.notFirstPlace = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.rank() != 1;
    });
```

Of course, this works. And hooray for Knockout JS which really is a lot of fun to use. But this just seems wrong. Anybody have a better method?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are using logical operations in data-bind attribute you should put `()` after observable or computed names.

```
<span class="badge" data-bind="text: rank, css: {'badge-success': firstPlace, 
    'badge-warning': !firstPlace()}"></span>
```

Comment: Accepted! Why didn't I try that? It can sometimes be hard to get my head around when to use parens and when not to. I usually end up using trial and error. I think this is the first time I have noticed both signatures in the same data-bind.

Comment: Most bindings are written to allow either syntax ... if there aren't parenthesis, it manually executes it anyway.  The only time the parenthesis CANNOT be added is when the binding is an "output", such as `value: obs`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to evaluate `firstPlace()` only *once*, you can write the `css` binding as an inline function:

```
<span class="badge" data-bind="text: rank, css: (firstPlace() ? 'badge-success' : 'badge-warning')"></span>
```